# How to return an integer when using generics?

Tags: java, generics, nullpointerexception

```
// returns the value of the current element (or -1)
    public T GetValue()
    {
      Node<T> temp = head;
      while(temp != curr)
      {
          temp = temp.next;
          if(temp == null)
          {
              return -1;
          }
      }
      return temp.data;
    }
```

My code is supposed to get the value at the current element and return that value. If it isn't found, then you return a -1. Running this code without the if statement gives me a Null pointer exception. I can't run the code with the if statement because of generics.

Comment: Either your function is supposed to return an int, or it's supposed to return -1. If its return type is T (and T is not some supertype of Integer), you can't return -1. Your requirements do not make sense.

Answer (score 2):

You can only return -1 if `T` is `Integer`; but then it wouldn't be generic.

You need some sort of special value which can't be mistaken for a "real" instance of `T`. For example, you could change the return type to `Optional<T>`, so you can return `Optional.empty()` to indicate a value wasn't found.

```
public Optional<T> GetValue() {
  // ...
      if(temp == null)
      {
          return Optional.empty();
      }
 // ...
 return Optional.of(temp.data);
```

}

Alternatively, you could provide a "not found" value to the constructor of your class, and return that when something isn't found:

```
class YourClass<T> {
  private final T notFoundValue; // Assign in constructor.

  // ...

  public T GetValue() {
    // ...
      if(temp == null)
      {
          return notFoundValue;
      }
    // ...
    return temp.data;
  } 
}
```

But you'd then have to be very careful to handle the possibility that `notFoundValue` was returned; making that explicit by returning something of a different (but related) type to `T`, such as `Optional<T>` is a good way to ensure this handling takes place.

Comment: For completeness, when the method returns `Optional<T>`, a caller using `Integer` for `T` can use `GetValue().orElse(-1)` to get the desired behavior.